# mysql forloop in select statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, mysql-python

i have list of dates

```
datefromto=['2018-06-16','2018-08-10','2018-09-12']
```

select query should flech for the given dates and store in csv file

```
for dates in datefromto:
      yesterbilling="""select * from student_date where date(datetime)= """+str(dates)+""" and daynumber="""+str(time.strftime("%w", time.strptime(dates, "%Y-%m-%d")))+""" and status='attended' """
      cursor.execute(yesterbilling)
      yesterbillings = cursor.fetchall()

     myFile = open(students.csv, 'w')
     with myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerows(yesterbillings)

    print("Writing complete")
```

This is working for single date without forloop. Mysql inside for loop is not working. No error but the data is not written. I wrote the with function outside for loop but no data is written in csv.

Help me please

Comment: I don't think you need a loop in this case. Couldn't you just find where all the dates are IN the list of dates? You should parameterize the query as well to defend against SQL injection etc.

Comment: @DanielGale: In sql statement their is day number (0 to 6) which is derived from dates in the list. that's the reason i am trying with for loop. Can you help

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

Option 1: Use `a` for appending instead of overwriting during each loop with `w`. Like this:

```
myFile = open(students.csv, 'a')
```

Option 2 (better): use SQL's `in` clause like this:

```
yesterbilling="select * from student_date where date(datetime) in ('" + "','".join(datefromto) + "') and status='attended' "
cursor.execute(yesterbilling)
yesterbillings = cursor.fetchall()

# now it's safe to use 'w' because the writing will be done at once
myFile = open(students.csv, 'w') 
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(yesterbillings)
```

And one more thing: if your python string won't span multiple lines, you don't need `"""`. Just use a single `"`.

Also, learn how to use:

- [Python string format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format)
- sql statements with parameters (safer, faster way of passing parameters to SQL sentences)

Comment: This wont help me because its has to be writing through forloop because their are other statement included inside sql statement like day number based on date.

Comment: Can you please help me through the for loop. correcting question with condition.

Comment: If you need to keep the `for` loop, just go with option 1. It is just a matter of changing `w` to an `a`. Nothing more than that in your code.

Comment: @pablojavierpy: Their is no issue with writing mode. If i print yesterbillings in the code. Its returning me empty result.